# Django-tables2 - column name is changed after refreshing page

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm facing a very weird behaviour of `Django` and `Django-tables2`.

I use table to help to render multiple types of documents.

For simplicity, there are two types of documents - 'faktura' and 'dobropis'.

'dobropis' has to have first column labeled "Dobropisujeme Vám" and 'faktura' - "Názov položky" + those columns are equal.

So I'm checking, if the type of Document is 'faktura' or 'dobropis' inside Table `__init__` function and accordingly set

`self.base_columns['column'].verbose_name = ...`

The weird thing is that it works, but only after second refresh.

Situation: I've opened 'faktura' page - I can see 'Názov položky' which is ok. Then I open 'dobropis' page and I see 'Názov položky' label again. Then, if I refresh again, there is 'Dobropisujeme Vám'. Then, after each refresh, I see correct label  -  'Dobropisujeme Vám'. But, if I open 'faktura' page, there is  'Dobropisujeme Vám' too for the first time, after second refresh it goes normal.

```
class PolozkyTable(tables.Table):
    nazov_polozky = tables.columns.Column(orderable=False)
    pocet = tables.columns.Column(orderable=False)
    jednotka = tables.columns.Column(orderable=False)
    cena = tables.columns.Column(orderable=False, verbose_name=u'Jednotková cena')
    zlava = tables.columns.Column(orderable=False)
    dph = tables.columns.Column(orderable=False)
    celkom = tables.columns.Column(orderable=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Polozka
        fields = ['nazov_polozky', 'pocet', 'jednotka', 'cena', 'zlava', 'dph', 'celkom']
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-hover'}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        typ = kwargs.pop('typ')
        super(PolozkyTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if typ == 'dobropis':
            self.base_columns['nazov_polozky'].verbose_name = u'Dobropisujeme Vám'
            self.exclude = ['zlava', 'dph']
        else:
            self.base_columns['nazov_polozky'].verbose_name = u'Názov položky'


    def render_cena(self, record):
        return '{} {}'.format(record.cena, record.doklad.get_fakturacna_mena_display().encode('utf-8'))

    def render_celkom(self, record):
        return '{} {}'.format(record.celkom, record.doklad.get_fakturacna_mena_display().encode('utf-8'))


@login_required
def doklad_detail(request):
    doklad = get_object_or_404(Doklad, pk=request.GET.get('id'))
    polozky_table = PolozkyTable(doklad.polozky.all(),typ=doklad.typ)
    return render(request, 'pdf/{}_pdf_template.html'.format(doklad.typ),
                  {'doklad': doklad, 'polozky_table': polozky_table})
```

There is no cache in this project and I really don't know what it could be.

Do you know?

**EDIT:**

Moreover, when I open 'faktura' after restarting the server, it shows camelcased 'Názov Položky' instead of 'Názov položky'. This is another weird thing because I searched whole project for case sensitive 'Názov Položky' and there is no such string.

**EDIT2:**

I've solved this creating separate table for 'dobropis' but I'm still curious which caused this problem. My colleague had the same problem on his PC.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be modifying `base_columns` in the `__init__` method -- you are changing the value on the class, so it affects other views as well.

The `base_columns` [have already been copied](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/4fb5427d142ba035aa282130fd44783c9cf1c75e/django_tables2/tables.py#L251) in the `super()` call before you alter them, so the changes only show up the next time you access the view.

It looks like you should be modifying `self.columns` instead. That should only affect the instance. Try setting `header` instead of `verbose_name`.

```
self.columns['nazov_polozky'].header = u'Dobropisujeme Vám'
```

Comment: The problem is that this approach raises >> Exception Value: 
can't set attribute <<. That's why I used base_columns. I found it on multiple places: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29747086/3371056 or http://ruddra.com/2015/09/18/make-a-blog-using-django-part-1/

Comment: Changing `base_column` might be suggested in multiple places, but as I explained, I think it's a mistake to change it because you're modifying the class. Try setting `header` instead of `verbose_name` on the column.

Comment: Why not just use two different table definitions?

Comment: @Jieter that comment would be better on the original question rather than the answer. The OP already said that they got it working with two columns. I've explained why setting `base_columns` is not a good idea.

Comment: self.columns['nazov_polozky'].column.verbose_name = u'new column name'